# Gulp + Rollup | Ошибка после сборки проекта

Tags: javascript, gulp, rollup

Использовал чистый Gulp и при компиляции получал на выходе код такого вида:

```
class useShowPassword {
    constructor(button, input) {
        if (!button || !input) throw 'Элементы не найдены';

        this.button = button;
        this.input = input;

        button.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleAttribute());
    }

    toggleAttribute() {
        const status = this.input.getAttribute('type') === 'text';
        this.input.setAttribute('type', status ? 'password' : 'text');
        status ? this.button.classList.remove('active') : this.button.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

---

Подключил Rollup с модулями и код стал выглядеть так:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define('showPassword', factory) :
    (global = global || self, global.showPassword = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

    class useShowPassword {
      constructor(button, input) {
        if (!button || !input) throw 'Элементы не найдены';
        this.button = button;
        this.input = input;
        button.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleAttribute());
      }

      toggleAttribute() {
        const status = this.input.getAttribute('type') === 'text';
        this.input.setAttribute('type', status ? 'password' : 'text');
        status ? this.button.classList.remove('active') : this.button.classList.add('active');
      }

    }

    return useShowPassword;

})));
```

---

В `html` я пытаюсь подключить файл и использовать его функционал:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- // -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script>
            const button = document.querySelector('.button');
            const input = document.querySelector('.input');
            new useShowPassword(button, input);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Соответственно получаю ошибку: `Uncaught ReferenceError: useShowPassword is not defined`

Сам файл `gulpconfig.js` изменился лишь на одну строчку:

```
.pipe(rollup({ plugins: [babel(), resolve(), commonjs()] }, 'umd'))
```

Здесь не столько проблема с конфигом, сколько с тем, как использовать собранный файл в проекте.

---

**upd**: Сам код, он работает, я просто не могу получить доступ к классу, т.к. он обрамлен после использования `Rollup`'a

Comment: а если не конст, а вар ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провел анализ кода и методом проб и ошибок выявил проблему.

Приведу пример не собранного кода:

```
export class foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log('foo');
    }
}
export class bar {
    constructor() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
```

Мы экспортируем два класса, `foo` и `bar`.

После сборки это выглядит вот так:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define('showPassword', ['exports'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory(global.showPassword = {}));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';

    class foo {
      constructor() {
        console.log('foo');
      }

    }
    class bar {
      constructor() {
        console.log('bar');
      }

    }

    exports.bar = bar;
    exports.foo = foo;

    Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

})));
```

Если заметить вверху `define('showPassword')` то можно догадаться, что обращаться нужно к нему, чтобы получить доступ к классам после.

На выходе я должен написать код следующим образом:

```
new showPassword.foo();
new showPassword.bar();
```

Беру название дефайна и название экспорта и на выходе работаю с классом как и хотел. **Все работает.**